# register multiple post types on one menu entry

Tags: custom-post-types

#### Case:

I `register_post_type()` 3 different CPTs<sup>1)</sup>

Example: 3 post types named *party, event, location*. The other needed arguments in the array are left out.

```
register_post_type(
     'party'
    ,array( 
        'show_in_menu' // true (for main) or "edit.php?post_type=party (for subentries)
     )
);
```

- Then I set the `'show_in_menu'` argument for the *first* CPT item (a.k.a "party") to `true`
- The other items get set `'show_in_menu'` to `'edit.php?post_type=party`

#### Result:

[image]

What's the point with this? What I expected was that I get "`Add New`" menu items for all of them, not only for the main CPT.

How would I do set the arguments to not only get list views, but single new/edit screens as well?

#### Notes:

I know, that I got an `Add New` button in the list view on top next to the title, but I want to know how I could add these links to the admin menu items.

I also know that I can work around with

```
add_submenu_page(
     "edit.php?post_type=party"
    ,"Add New"
    ,"Add New"
    ,"post-new.php?post_type=party"
);
```

but I'm not interested in the work around. I want to know how this is thought to work out of the box.

<sup>1) CPT = short for custom post type</sup>

Comment: As for as I can tell they simply don't work like this, even using `submenu_page` can have ordering problems, I have had to unset them all and add them in the order I wanted.

Comment: @Wyck Would you mind adding a snippet as answer? It seems like I have to be satisfied with the massive set of work arounds, like I already had to find out [with separators](https://gist.github.com/1324722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customizing the menu this way is as for as I can tell,  not very friendly. What I had to do recently was custom built the submenu item using `remove_submenu_page` for all the sub menu items and then add them in the order I wanted using `add_submenu_page`.

A simple example

```
 //this was first sub-menu item I did not want it #1
 remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=test', 'edit.php?post_type=test' );

 // add the actual sub-menu item I wanted as #1
 add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=hello','Hello', 'Hello', 'manage_options', 'my_hello', 'my_hello_options');

//re-add the orginal #1 item removed above so it is now the #2 item
 add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=test','Edit Test', 'Edit Test', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=test');
```

---

**Edit:** If you plan on using the `menu_order` filter, it's pretty simple to get the filter working: Just add this line before it. Else it would skip the `menu_order` filter: `add_filter( 'custom_menu_order', '__return_true' );`.

Comment: So ordering happens simply by adding it step by step?

Comment: I think so, not 100% sure, the alternative would be something crazy like this, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28861/order-admin-sub-menu-items

Comment: Ok, seems to still crazy removing and adding, but as there's no way around this: Thanks a lot!